# Add class to jqgrid column whose type is checkbox

Tags: jqgrid

I want to add a special class of column whose type is check box. is there any cell attr function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
cellattr: function(rowId, val, rawObject) {
return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+rawObject[“checkbox_object_database”]+”’ class=‘class_name’/>“;
}
```